# Want to know ActiveX control alternative in java

Tags: java, activex

I have need to create something like activeX controls, in which I can send messages from client to server. 
Can someone please tell me the alternative of ActiveX controls in java or can I create ActiveX controls in java. I know ActiveX control is product of microsoft.

I know about the applets, one alternative of ActiveX controls in java. Is there more alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there someone who can answer????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sockets/RMI to send and receive messages in java. I hope this will work for you.